# How to add a directive (formControlName) to an component instance?

Tags: angular, typescript, controlvalueaccessor

I try to dynamically create input forms with form support.
It is working just fine, since i can add the directive "formControlName" directly on the html-element.

But now i dont know how i can set the directive to the instance of a dynamically created component which takes place instead of a ng-template.

the directive myCustomComponentDirective creates a Component by a given Type (with ComponentFactoryResolver) and render it into the ng-template.
The CustomComponent implements the controlValueAccessor and works if the formControlName directive is tagged directly on it.

How to add a directive like "formControlName" dynamically in the directive myCustomComponentDirective?

component.html:

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">

<ng-container *ngFor="let singleForm of formConfigs;">

    <ng-container [ngSwitch]="singleForm?.type">
    
        <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'input'">
            <input formControlName="singleForm.conrolName" >
        </ng-container>
        
        <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'custom'">
            <!-- next line will not working since ng-template hasnt a nativeElement property -->
            <!-- <ng-template myCustomComponentDirective formControlName="singleForm.conrolName"></ng-template> -->
            
            <div myCustomComponentDirective formControlName="singleForm.conrolName"></div>
        </ng-container>
    
    </ng-container>


</ng-container>
```

the directive where i want to set formControlName:

```
Directive({
selector: '[customComponentDirective]',
})
export class ComponentDirective implements OnInit
{
@Input() customComponentDirective: Type<any>;

constructor(private _viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
    private _componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver){}

    private _appendDirective(){
        // here i want to add the directive when the component has been created....
        mycreatedInstace.addDirective(formControlName);
    }
}
```